# Is it possible to watch Netflix on Firefox 48?

Tags: firefox, drm

I've read that Firefox now supports DRM, but I don't know if it's already on Ubuntu, do you know if it works? Thanks.

Comment: Can't you try it?

Comment: I'm thinking on buying an account, but I will use it on Firefox, if it doesn't work I won't be able to see the videos...

Comment: Ah. Well if it doesn't work, you can always use Chrome. I'll check if it works.

Comment: FF 48 asks me to download the Silverlight plugin, so I'm going to say it doesn't work. Use Chrome if you end up getting Netflix.

Comment: Pipelight seems to be an alternative to Silverlight for Firefox. Just in case you insist on going with FF. http://pipelight.net/cms/installation.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have noted, Netflix won't play in the Linux version of Firefox 48.

But Netflix can be played in the Linux version of Firefox 49, which is currently in beta, and can be installed from ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next.

Once Firefox 49 is installed, you'll need to be certain that the Widevine plugin is installed and activated.  (It wasn't installed/activated by default for me.) Also, because Netflix doesn't yet officially support playback on the Linux version Firefox, at least for now, you'll need to use a "User Agent Switcher" set to reflect a recent Linux version of Chrome.

You can find more information here: http://www.ghacks.net/2016/08/13/firefox-49-linux-netflix-amazon-video/

For what it's worth, at least for me, Netflix currently plays better in Chrome than in Firefox.  But Firefox 49 is still in beta, so maybe things will improve.

Comment: Thanks! Great, so in about 1 month Firefox will support Netflix on Linux!

Answer (score 3):

I just tried to stream Netflix on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine with Firefox 48.

The site itself works fine, but once I try to start a stream, Netflix asks me to install the Silverlight plugin, which, of course is Windows only.

So no, it doesn't seem possible to watch Netflix on Ubuntu with Firefox. If you do buy the service, you'll have to use Chrome (Chromium doesn't work).

Comment: @Zanna I didn't, but idc ;p

Comment: @Roque we'll see I guess.